# Как это слово называется?

Tags: определения, терминология

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, существует ли в русском языке слово (возможно заимствованное, впоследствии ставшее интернациональным), являющееся собирательным для обозначения человека (либо самого явления) с низкой культурой речи, косноязычным слогом, скудным словарным запасом.

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: @N3ver_Again, если вы видите какую-либо техническую ошибку, пожалуйста, опишите ее как можно более подробно на [Мете](http://meta.hashcode.ru).

Comment: Само явление в стилистике называется **речевой недостаточностью**. 

Answer (score 3):

Я бы назвал такого человека **черномырденцем**. Еще можно вспомнить **Эллочку-людоедку**. По аналогии с вульгарной лытынью явление можно назвать *вульгарным (народным) русским*, хотя мне последний вариант не нравится.

Comment: Примеры исключительно уместные, однако являются именами нарицательными (совершенно, как и вышеупомянутые), а хотелось бы знать "без отчеств". :)

Answer (score 1):

**Чернобай**.
Правда оно стало означать еще и ругающегося человека, сквернослова, но исходное значение окончательно не выветрилось.

Еще его можно назвать **косноязычным** - это это не совсем однозначное соответствие. Косноязычие все-таки не совсем синоним **скудоречию** - невежественной речи.

Еще раньше таких людей называли наряду с иностранцами **немцами**. Но это сейчас совершенно устарело.

Движок у сайта - какой есть. Привыкли. Хотя согласен, выбор его вызывает недоумение.

Comment: Благодарствую!
Мельком навестил ссылки Гуглера, там действительно Чернобай упомянут только в виде сквернослова-бескультурника.

Не могли бы Вы лишь уточнить, где было Вами обнаружено данное слово?
(Дома один словарь Даля, и тот не под рукой, справочников больше нету).

Comment: К сожалению, источники теряются  в лете. Помню, что именно в таком значении я его слышал и обсуждал, кажется - в связи с фамилией.  
Вообще такие вещи всегда надо проверять по словарю русских народных говоров, но в сети он есть только в виде многогигабайтных сканов - попробую залезть, но, боюсь, мой интернет не выдержит.  
  
Если у вас есть доступ к оному творению или много интерената - попробуйте там посмотреть.  
Ссылку сейчас найду.

Вот сюда попробуйте заглянуть
http://iling.spb.ru/vocabula/srng/srng.html

Это считалось лучшим вариантом электронной версии

Comment: Можете не утруждаться, уже нашёл указанную Вами литературу, спасибо за совет!

ссылку увидел, мерси!

Answer (score 1):

А вот еще: мужлан, деревенщина, колхозник, бурбон, бурлан.

Comment: За бурбона - спасибо :) .
Я наивный всю жизнь думал, что это разновидность крепкого алкогольного напитка.